# Windows Batch script to get filename as input and search the file in a folder location

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a windows batch file which includes 3 tasks mainly:

1.It will ask for the user input like:

```
Please Enter file name to search:
```

where you have to give a file name and depending on the file name it will search in some specified location.

2.If the file is found ,again it will search for some pattern(e.g-"Error") in that file.

3.Copy 10 lines from the line where the pattern was found and paste the contents into another file.

Example:

You have entered file name as: **DemoFile**
1.It will search for **DemoFile.log** in specified location.

2.If above file is found then it will search for some pattern(e.g-"Error").

3.Suppoese pattern *Error* was found in line #20 ,then it will copy the contents from line #20 to line #30 to another file(**MyDemoFile.txt**).

It seems quite complex. Anyhow need help badly.

Thanks in advance  :)

Below is my code  snippet in which it prompts the user for file name.

```
@ECHO OFF


*** Prompting user to enter the id*****
SET /P uname=Please enter the conversation id: 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
ECHO Entered Conversation Id : %uname%, Below Are the Log files related to this id:

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (a.txt) DO echo %%x

*** finding files based on that conversation id****
set LISTFOLDER=C:\Users\demo\Desktop\stats\test\a.txt -- passing parameter as conversation id
set FILESPATH=\\test\*.log
set DESTPATH=C:\Users\demo\Desktop\stats\test\check

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b ^"%LISTFOLDER%\*.txt^"') do (call :COPY_FILES "%LISTFOLDER%\%%i")

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

### Basics

Heads up. I'm not going to solve this with just pure batch and built-in Windows tools. (Debatable, actually. Read on!) I'm going to assume that the environment isn't 100% locked down and that we can use a slightly better tool for part 3.

Based on the question, the sample code, and some comments, we want to prompt for a subpattern of a file name and search through all the files in one directory that match that pattern.

### Batch

Here's a way to prompt for, check whether any files exist in the given directory, and—if so—find the lines that match. (Parts 1 and 2)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /P file=Please enter the thing you want to search in: 

SET logfiles=some\path\to\%file%*.log

IF EXIST "%logfiles%" (
    FINDSTR /I /P Error "%logfiles%" > "some\output\path\%file%_results.log"
) ELSE (
    ECHO No matches for "%logfiles%" found.
    EXIT /B 1
)
```

Going into subdirectories is left as an exercise.

Part 3, getting the 10 lines after a match is trickier. It may be possible with what I'd call "silly batch tricks". I can't come up with them now. Suggestions and edits welcome.

However, I personally, would solve that problem with a different tool, assuming I could. I'm going to assume that we can.

### PowerShell

[PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is installed by default on many configurations of Windows starting from Windows 7/Windows Server 2008R2. It's [`Select-String`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=294008) cmdlet has a `-Context` parameter that can control how many lines of context is included. A cmdlet like the following is the skeleton that I'd start with. I'm intentionally *not* writing to an output file in the cmdlet to be able to take advantage of PowerShell's pipeline later. This is a decision that you can easily change.

```
function Get-ErrorFromLog {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Search through logs that match and extract the error lines and some context
  .EXAMPLE
  Get-ErrorFromLog -Log server
  .PARAMETER Log
  The base name of the log to search through. .log is automatically appended and we automatically search in SearchBase
  .PARAMETER SearchBase
  The directory to look in for logs
  #>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
    HelpMessage='What log would you like to search in?')]
    [string]$Log,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [string]$SearchBase='some\path'
  )

  $logfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchBase -Filter ($Log + '*.log') -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

  if ($logfiles) {
      $logfiles | Select-String -Pattern 'error' -Context 0,10
  } else {
      Write-Error "No items matchings `"$Log*.log`" exist in $SearchBase"
  }
}
```

Some example output

```
PS D:\> Get-ErrorFromLog -Log does-not-exist
Get-ErrorFromLog : No items matchings "does-not-exist*.log" exist in some\path
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ErrorFromLog -Log does-not-exist
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-ErrorFromLog


PS D:\> Get-ErrorFromLog -Log does-not-exist -SearchBase D:\temp\search
Get-ErrorFromLog : No items matchings "does-not-exist*.log" exist in D:\temp\search
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ErrorFromLog -Log does-not-exist -SearchBase D:\temp\search
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-ErrorFromLog


PS D:\> # d:\temp\search\a.log exists, but has no errors

PS D:\> Get-ErrorFromLog -Log a -SearchBase D:\temp\search

PS D:\> Get-ErrorFromLog -Log b -SearchBase D:\temp\search

> temp\search\b.log:8:8 Error
  temp\search\b.log:9:9 Attempting recovery
  temp\search\b.log:10:10 Recovery in progress
  temp\search\b.log:11:11 Recovery finished
  temp\search\b.log:12:12 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b.log:13:13 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b.log:14:14 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b.log:15:15 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b.log:16:16 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b.log:17:17 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b.log:18:18 Nothing wrong at this time
> temp\search\b2.log:8:8 Error
  temp\search\b2.log:9:9 Attempting recovery
  temp\search\b2.log:10:10 Recovery in progress
  temp\search\b2.log:11:11 Recovery finished
  temp\search\b2.log:12:12 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b2.log:13:13 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b2.log:14:14 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b2.log:15:15 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b2.log:16:16 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b2.log:17:17 Nothing wrong at this time
  temp\search\b2.log:18:18 Nothing wrong at this time
```

Going into subdirectories is left as an exercise. It's really easy in PowerShell. Check the documentation for [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204557).

### grep

Some Windows environments have some version of a [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) tool installed, and most modern version of grep have a way of controlling the amount of context after a match to print. In our example, we'd use something like the following instead of the `FINDSTR` command.

```
grep --with-filename --after-context=10 --ignore-case error "%logfiles%" > "%file%_results.log"
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks  for your input.

Here you are searching the user provided file in current working directory  i.e.  where the .cmd file exists.

But I need to search the file from a specified location(e.g-\\test\*.log)

Hope you get my requirement.  :)

Comment: I think I understand now. Going from the current directory to some other directory is a simple change. I'm sure you could have done it yourself easily. Though, the need to search through multiple files wasn't quite clear from the question. Consider editing the question to clarify as phrases like "If the file is found" imply only one file.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
Yes its bit easy to change the dir. But scenario is like:
I have to prompt user to enter an Id (ex: Customer Id as r12345) and then from this inputted id , script will search for the file with same name (as r12345) in a folder and then read that file for any error into it and print the next 10 line below that "error" word.
Here I am able to prompt user for providing input and able to search for error in the file but not able to search file in the folder. Its being good if you have any idea about it.

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information. I'm still unclear on which file (or files) need to be the target of the search for error. The question would be better if it included a directory tree and examples of inputs and what file or files should match. The answer as written will find all files matching the user's input (assuming a .log extension--if not, just change that) in the target directory. Also, be aware that StackOverflow is not a place to get code written for you from spec. It's to help get answers to technical questions. To get code written from spec, hire a programmer.